# Word for "Ray of Hope"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, synonyms

Which word or phrase to use instead of "Ray of Hope" ?

EDIT : In a general context.

Suppose there is one line - There is a Ray Of Hope in darkness always.

Comment: Ray of hope seems perfectly fine itself; so it would help if you could describe what it is about *ray of hope* that you don't like/doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar phrases include "shaft of light" or "light at the end of the tunnel". If you're looking for something more formal, perhaps "potential opportunity" or "possibile solution" might fit the bill. A lot depends on the context in which the phrase is to be used.

Answer (score 2):

["Silver lining"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_lining_%28idiom%29) comes to mind as one expression for new hope.

Answer (score 1):

"Beacon of hope" and "beacon of light" come to mind.  However, they are not quite the same in that they don't imply a darkness 'elsewhere' in the way "light at the end of the tunnel" or "silver lining" does.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest saying *guiding light*. If used in a spiritual sense, then you could say  *eternal guide*.